# UI Bootstrap typeahead blank dropdown issue

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the type ahead and all seems to be working. The only problem is something with the styling is wrong, it displays the dropdown like it is going to autocomplete but it is all blank.. the values are there and in fact if you hit enter they work.. but aren't being displayed

[image]

I should mention that I am using AngularJS with Ionic...

I'll paste my code here just in case.. any help would be great!

HTML:

```
<!-- UI BootStrap style sheet and js -->
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.4.0.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class='container-fluid' >
    <pre>Model: {{Selected| json}}</pre>
    <!-- <input type="text" ng-model="selected" typeahead="state for state in states | filter:$viewValue"> -->
    <input type="text" ng-model="Selected" typeahead="Unidade.Codigo as Unidade.Nome for Unidade in Unidades | filter:$viewValue | limitTo:8" class="form-control" />
</div>
```

and the Javascript.. I doubt this is the problem but can't hurt

```
 $scope.Selected = undefined;
  $scope.Unidades = [{
        "Nome": "laskjdhflksjfg",
        "Codigo": "11106600"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "wertwertwertwer",
        "Codigo": "11106601"
    },
    {
        "Nome": "wertwertwertwer",
        "Codigo": "11106602"
    }];
```

I actually copied this example from here: http://plnkr.co/edit/1Sm17103S73nJbpb2PmK?p=preview
So I know it works....

Thanks Guys!

Comment: Check your CSS import order and inspect the input with dev tools to verify if  correct CSS is applied and not overridden.

Comment: It's on my desktop machine so I'll have to check when i get home but if I find that my CSS is overidden is the only remedy to just change the import order?

Comment: thanks for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need Bootstrap together with Ionic?

There are some post on Ionic forum relating the question, for example https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-twitters-bootstrap-css-framework-again/8269/6

CSS classes of Bootstrap could interfere with Ionic ones.

Why not using [Ionic Autocomplete](https://github.com/guylabs/ion-autocomplete) or other similar components?

Comment: welp. to be honest didn't realize that was a thing. Thanks!

Comment: I mean the UI Bootstrap Typeahead that seems 10x nicer

Comment: but have you done a custom build including in the ui-bootstrap only uib-typeahead component?

Comment: nope.. I used to only develop in java so a lot of this stuff is new.. how would I go about that? Strip out any classes in the css besides the typeahead one? Is there an easier way

Comment: yes, go to https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ and  click on "create a build", select only the directives you want and download your custom build

Comment: ahh, somethings wrong with my css.. maybe i'll just go with that ionic thing. not worth the effort

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm If the values are coming onto the DOM using Inspect Element or such and send the screenshots. Because this usually happens when there is an **empty string**. Like in this screenshot.

[image]

Your code according to your screenshot seems to behave the same. Also can you please elaborate when you say - when I hit enter it works. What do you see as the `Model:` value when you hit enter ?